# Can anyone help me to understand why the GMV point is not on the efficient frontier?

Tags: programming, finance-mathematics, modern-portfolio-theory, minimum-variance

I am following a course about portfolio construction with Python. I am able to successfully draw the efficient frontier and capital market line (CML), and the global minimum variance (GMV) point using daily returns of different assets. However, when I try to lower the frequency to 15 minutes or 5 minutes, the CML (green) and GMV(blue) points are plotted in a weird way. The CML becomes non-tangent and doesn't belong to the frontier, and the GMV point does not belong to the efficient frontier.

[image]

I have attached the code that I am using.

main :

https://pastebin.com/Y1k5rCk4

efflib :

https://pastebin.com/m3XJGEnD

Can anyone help me to understand why this happens?

Comment: Either a bug in the code or an improper covariance matrix. Make sure the covariance matrix is square, symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: @nbbo2 i double checked the covariance matrix (square, symmetric and positive definite) its all well, i think the problem is in the minimize (msr function inside the code ) function , maybe the values  of the  weights  are too big